# yii registerScriptFile does not work

Tags: yii

I've added this code at the top of **themes/bootstrap/views/layouts/main.php**

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile(Yii::app()->baseUrl . '/js/custom.js');
```

in my html it does show

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/dev2/js/custom.js"></script>
</head>
```

and in the `custom.js` file i have this

```
jQuery(function($) {
   alert('test');
}
```

when the page loads, i don't get any alert showing. the files do exist in the right directory and i get no firebug warnings. All JS files that i've manually included using `registerScriptFile` for some reason doesn't work. None of my plugins i've included work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
alert('hello');
// Enter code here
});
```

in your custom.js .

Answer (score 0):

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile(Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/js/custom', CClientScript::POS_HEAD);
```

and wrong in script:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    alert('test');
});
```

have to work